# preg_match_all can't find html

Tags: php, regex

I have problem with my php regular expression, this is my code:

```
<div class="editor-content">
    <h2 id="sec_1"><b>Description</b></h2>
    <p><strong>This is my long description</strong></p>

    <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>

    <h2 id="sec_2"><b>Details</b></h2>
    <p><strong>This is my long product details</strong></p>

    <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and i need:
1. Find all between

```
`<div class="editor-content">(.*?)</div>`
```

2. If i have all between

   `<div class="editor-content">(.*?)</div>`

then i need get all section, i mean for example:

```
<h2 id="sec_1"><b>Description</b></h2>
    <p><strong>This is my long description</strong></p>

    <ul>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
        <li>lorem ipsum</li>
    </ul>
```

I mean to find all sections in such a way that e.g. starts with sec_1 and preg_match gets everything until sec_2 starts, sec_2 starts, preg_match gets everything until sec_3.

Current i have this expression:

```
    $re = '/^<div class="editor-content">(.*?)</div>/';

    preg_match_all($re, $body, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
    var_dump($matches);
```

but he finds nothing.

Comment: You‘ll need `dotall` (`/.../s`) or a parser altogether.

Comment: You should *never* parse HTML with regex. Use [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) instead.